# django rest framework: forms how to pass the select options

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a form in reactjs as frontend, which will create an object using Django api

I am trying to create an ingredient

the following is the serializer to create or update and ingredient

```
class IngredientCreateUpdateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = [
            'name',
            'munit',
            'rate',
            'typeofingredient',
        ]
```

I will be having munit and typeofingredient as select fields.

The options for these select fields have to supplied from the server.

eg: munit can have options of kg,ltr, pcs etc
and typeofingredient can have option of vegetables, spices, fruits etc

both are ForeignKey type.

So prior to using the create api i have to supply to the form the options of both munit and typeofingredient at that particular instance from the server.

So how to do this. For getting the options should i have to create another api. or is there any direct way

Answer (score 0):

If both typeofingredient and munit are foreign keys then you can define serializers for each of those models and use list api to populate select options.

If you want to combine both Serializers in a single api, you can do the same thing in the ViewSet.

views.py

```
#Assuming MunitOptionsSerializer and TypeOfIngredientOptionsSerializer are 
#your serializers
class IngredientOptionsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def list(self, request):
        # assuming MunitOptions & TypeOfIngredientOptions are the models
        qs = MunitOptions.objects.all()
        s1 = MunitOptionsSerializer(qs, many=True)
        qs = TypeOfIngredientOptions.objects.all()
        s2 = TypeOfIngredientOptionsSerializer(qs, many=True)
        return Response({'munit':s1.data, 'typeofingredient':s2.data})
```

In your app urls.py

```
options_list = OptionsViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'list',
})
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
urlpatterns = patterns(
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^options/$', options_list, name='options-list'),
)
```

Also make 'read only' restriction at ViewSet by inheriting them from ReadOnlyModelViewSet instead of ModelViewSet, since you will be using those serializers only for list/retrieve functions.

Comment: how to combine two list serializers so that i can create one list combined

Comment: You want to combine both the select option values (serializers) in a single api ?? You can do the combining logic in the viewset. I will update answer accordingly.

Comment: that will be helpful. I dont much idea